# document.writeln does not load remote jQuery script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to dynamically load content from an S3 pre-signed URL. I am using `document.writeln()` to dynamically load content. The remote jQuery and other libraries do not load.

```js
var url = "S3 Pre-signed url";

fetch(url).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
  var lines = data.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    if (line.toUpperCase().indexOf("<SCRIPT ") >= 0) {
      if (line.indexOf("$") < 0) {
        var index1 = line.toUpperCase().indexOf("<SCRIPT ");
        var before_line = line.substring(0, index1 - 9);

        var index2 = line.indexOf(">");
        var sub = line.substring(index1 - 8, index2);
        var after_line = line.substring(index2 + 1);
        //var sub2  = sub.substring(0,index2-1);

        sub += " async >";
        //sub = sub.replace(/"/g, '\"');
        var line2 = before_line + sub + after_line;

        line2 = line2.replace(/<\/script>/g, "<\/script>")
        document.writeln(line2)
      } else {
        //console.log("Index of $")
        document.writeln(line)
      }
    } else {
      document.writeln(line)
    }
  }
})
```

This is the error:

> VM413:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at :1:1

Comment: ["Warning: Use of the document.writeln() method is strongly discouraged."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/writeln).

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined," typically occurs when jQuery is not properly loaded or accessible in your code.

Comment: @Andy Please give some workaround

Comment: @DikshaChaudhary Hi , I have tried using async for loading jquery libraries as mentioned in google chrome site, even then it is not working, please help

Comment: @chiku In the browser->source code you can check either jQuery is loaded or not. 
If the JQuery is loaded then you might need to check your code runs after JQuery is fully loaded in the web page.

Comment: Did you tried not to use `async`? I think this is the problem, you may load jQuery after the code that use it.

Comment: @jcubic I agree with u, the problem is with our vendor API, which sends the S3 HUGE html download link (approx 10MB - 100 MB size) and we need to display the HTML in browser, pls lemme know for a workaround

Comment: I think that you need to replace all the scripts on the page with async including the code that uses jQuery, not only the first script that is on the page. Try to use regular expressions for that.

Comment: Also, can you share an example of HTML code that you've got, without seeing HTML it's really hard to say what is wrong.